# Writing to array element [i][0][1] also overwrites [i][1][0] and vice versa

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have an array:

```
typedef short int long_graph[1000][1000][1];
```

I declare it:

```
long_graph paf_graph;
```

I have a function:

```
void construct_paf_graph (sf::Vector2i A,sf::Vector2i B, long_graph &paf_graph, long_list &paf_list, poly_list &poly, int &no_of_poly_on_map, list_of_indexes &XX  )
{

short int n,i,j,k,e, t, off;  // t is used to convert indices from individual     polies to the unified list
bool path_clear;
short int distance, rev_en_ind; // reverse engineer index

n=0; //will be total number of points in paf_graph and paf_list
t=0;

std::fstream debug;
debug.open("assets/debug.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);

for ( i=1; i<=XX[0]; i+=1 )
{
        debug << XX[i] << "\n";
        for ( j=1; j<= poly[XX[i]].point[0].x; j+=1 )
            {
                n+=1;
                paf_graph[n][0][0] = poly[XX[i]].graph[j][0][0];
                //paf_graph[n][0][1] = i;
                debug << "P["<<n<<"] = " << paf_graph[n][0][1] << " \n";

                for (k=1; k<= poly[XX[i]].graph[j][0][0]; k+=1)
                    {
                            paf_graph[n][k][0] = poly[XX[i]].graph[j][k][0] + t;
                            paf_graph[n][k][1] = poly[XX[i]].graph[j][k][1];
                            debug << "   P["<<n<<"] = " << paf_graph[n][0][1] << " " << "k="<<k<< " c="<<poly[XX[i]].graph[j][k][0] + t<<" \n";
                            if (k==1) debug << "\n\n PP = " << paf_graph[n][k][0] << " " << poly[XX[i]].graph[j][k][0] + t <<"\n";
                    }

                off = paf_graph[n][1][0];
                paf_graph[n][0][1] = i;
                //paf_graph[n][1][0] = off;

                paf_list[n].x = poly[XX[i]].point[j].x;
                paf_list[n].y = poly[XX[i]].point[j].y;

            }
            debug << "\n";

t+= poly[XX[i]].point[0].x;
}

paf_graph[0][0][0] = n;
paf_list[0].x = n;
// function continues some more
```

I detected the problem here:

```
            //paf_graph[n][0][1] = i; //this was not commented originally
            debug << "P["<<n<<"] = " << paf_graph[n][0][1] << " \n";

            for (k=1; k<= poly[XX[i]].graph[j][0][0]; k+=1)
                {
                        paf_graph[n][k][0] = poly[XX[i]].graph[j][k][0] + t; //when k is 0 e.g. [n][1][0] it also overwrites [n][0][1] with the value
                        paf_graph[n][k][1] = poly[XX[i]].graph[j][k][1];
                        debug << "   P["<<n<<"] = " << paf_graph[n][0][1] << " " << "k="<<k<< " c="<<poly[XX[i]].graph[j][k][0] + t<<" \n";
                        if (k==1) debug << "\n\n PP = " << paf_graph[n][k][0] << " " << poly[XX[i]].graph[j][k][0] + t <<"\n";
                }
```

To isolate this strange phenomenon I put 3 extra lines as seen in the larger code block:

```
 off = paf_graph[n][1][0];
 paf_graph[n][0][1] = i; //this line also writes i to [n][1][0]
 //paf_graph[n][1][0] = off; //if I take the comment off this line it will
                             // write "off" to [n][0][1] as well
                             //so whatever I do they both have the same value
                             //and one is always wrong
```

The strange thing is the array itself is [1000][1000][1] of short int and for any other coordinates it works fine.
I have tried making it smaller [100][100][1], but the problem is the same, the values being passed are lower than 100 so well within short int.

The array is passed as a reference to the function and I use it afterwards in the main block and all values are set as expected except [i][0][1] and [i][1][0].

Unfortunately I can't post all of the code since it's very large, but I have double checked with a lot of logging that the issue is isolated to the part described above.

If anyone has any idea why this strange behavior is happening please help.

I've also tagged codeblocks since that is what I'm using perhaps it's a known error with the mingw compiler ?

Anyway, thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After simplifying your use case, your bug becomes very obvious.

Let's use a simple, one dimensional array whose size is equal to the size of the last dimension of your array. Instead of:

```
typedef short int long_graph[1000][1000][1];
```

Let's just use a one-dimensional array whose size is the same as the size of the last dimension:

```
typedef short int tiny_graph[1];
```

Now, you have such thing declared:

```
 tiny_graph x;
```

Now ask yourself a question: what are the valid array indexes here?

The answer is very obvious. Only one: `x[0]`. This array has only one value, and as you know, array indexes start at 0.

Now, let's go back to your array:

```
typedef short int long_graph[1000][1000][1];
```

And let's look at the problematic statement:

```
paf_graph[n][0][1] = i
```

Your bug should now be very obvious. There is no `paf_graph[n][0][1]`, since `[0]` is the last valid index of the last, the third, dimension of this array. And because of the way that arrays decay to pointers, and pointer arithmetic, this ends up addressing the `[0]` of the next higher-dimension's array.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I fell for such a rookie mistake.